# how to change max number of clients in hostednetwork

Tags: windows, cmd, wifi

I created a wifi hotspot in windows using

```
 netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=arby key=87654321
```

and then started it using

```
 netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Now when I give the command,

```
 netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

It shows `Max number of clients: 2`

How can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It shows Max number of clients: 2

"Max number of clients" is the smaller of two values:

- The hardware's capability, and
- The administrative configuration.

It is possible that your WiFi hardware doesn't support more than two clients.

To remove any possiblity that some other program has set the max clients to 2, try the following (Note that this will delete the SSID and key that you've configured, so you will to add them again)

```
net stop wlansvc
reg delete hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\wlansvc\parameters\hostednetworksettings /v hostednetworksettings
net start wlansvc
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=arby key=87654321
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

If the max clients limit has not increased, you may have to get a new wireless adapter.

Source [hosted network is allowing only one client at a time](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/80f23e58-bf78-41e5-beca-57ce197916db/hosted-network-is-allowing-only-one-client-at-a-time)

Comment: What is I want to reduce the number of clients?

Comment: @Daniel I don't think that is possible from the command line. You would need to write a program. See [WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_SETTINGS structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439499%28VS.85%29.aspx): `dwMaxNumberOfPeers`

    The maximum number of concurrent peers allowed by the wireless Hosted Network.